# jQuery: link to an anchor (hidden div) and show?

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have a div, "section" on a page, samplepage.html that I have set the display to "none"

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<a name="print">
        <div class="section" style="display:none">
            <p>Loreum ipsum text</p>
        </div>
```

When the user clicks from another page:

```
<a href="samplepage.html#print">link</a>
```

I would like to make the "section" div slide open (slideToggle)...is this possible? I don't know how to trigger an event from a click handler on another page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, in a `ready` handler:

```
if(document.location.hash) {
    $('.' + document.location.hash.substring(1)).slideDown();
}
```

Comment: I actually had to use this because I typed my question incorrectly: $('a[name="'+anchor+'"] .section') but the tip helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several libs for handling url routes like this. You may take a look a backbone.js route: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router

I would recommend this if you have a lot of routing in your app